# Write to OpenGL multiple renderbuffer failed

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, fbo

Not sure what is the problem, it failed to read the pixels when writing to multiple renderbuffer. Here is the code:

setup code:

```
// gen framebuffer object
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

// gen renderbuffer 0
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbo_color0);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo_color0);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGB, w, h);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo_color0);

// gen renderbuffer 1
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbo_color1);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo_color1);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RED_INTEGER, w, h);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo_color1);

// gen depth buffer
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbo_depth);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo_depth);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, w, h);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo_depth);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

render and read pixel code:

```
// setup shader and uniforms...
// bind framebuffer and clear color/depth buffer
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.1f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

const GLuint buffers[] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1};
glDrawBuffers(2, buffers);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, index_count, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)0);
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, data);
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);
glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_INT, (int*)(data) + 4);
glBindVertexArray(0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

I used layout qualifier in the shader for the outputs, shouldn't be any problems there. So I think probably there is something wrong the the buffer setup or render code.
I've succeed in reading the pixels when there is only one renderbuffer(rbo_color0). The main difference is:

1. no generation code for renderbuffer1;
2. use glDrawBuffer(rbo_color0) when rendering;
3. the format of rbo_color0 is GL_RGBA(double checked the format setting in corresponding glRenderbufferStorage/glReadBuffer calls, no problem here);
4. no read pixel call for rbo_color1.

Any helps?

Comment: good idea to have more error check, something like glGetError

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GL_RED_INTEGER` is not a proper internal format, as it can be used for the 2nd parameter of [`glRenderbufferStorage`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glRenderbufferStorage.xhtml).
A proper enumerator constant for the internal format would be `GL_R32I`.
See [OpenGL 4.6 API Compatibility Profile Specification; 8.26. TEXTURE IMAGE LOADS AND STORES; page 334](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.compatibility.pdf)

If you would check for OpenGL erros ([`glGetError`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetError.xhtml)), then you would get an `INVALID_ENUM` error.

Change the render buffer storage specification, to solve the issue:

```
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_R32I, w, h);
```

---

Note, you should check the framebuffer completeness by [`glCheckFramebufferStatus`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glCheckFramebufferStatus.xhtml):

```
GLenum fb_status = glCheckFramebufferStatus( GL_FRAMEBUFFER );
if ( fb_status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE )
{
  // error handling
}
```

Comment: One could add that `GL_RED_INTEGER` is also not valid for `glReadPixels`.

Comment: @derhass: Except that it very much is valid. `GL_RED, GL_INT` will read *floating point values*, converted into normalized, 32-bit signed integers. If you want to read integer values from an integer texture, you have to use the `_INTEGER` formats. The specification makes this clear; the *format* parameter of `glReadPixels` is defined in section 8.4.4, and nothing in there says that `_INTEGER` is forbidden for `glReadPixels`, no matter what those HTML pages say.

Comment: tested, GL_RED_INTEGER works in glReadPixels, thank you guys.